# how to return multiple values in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

Here is my code:

```
function get_roles(){
$role = array("1"=>"user management", "2"=>"create", "3"=>"update","4"=>"publish", "5"=>"delete", "6"=>"image upload", "7"=>"advertisement", "8"=>"department", "9"=>"category", "10"=>"sub category", "11"=>"grievance", "12"=>"feedback", "13"=>"help");
foreach($role as $x => $x_value) {
$result=  $x_value;   
}
return $result;
}
echo get_roles();
```

I want to return all values as json in php. But it returns only last value. How to do that? Is it possible to return all values?

Comment: `return json_encode($role)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please use json_encode()**

```
function get_roles(){
$role = array("1"=>"user management", "2"=>"create", "3"=>"update","4"=>"publish", "5"=>"delete", "6"=>"image upload", "7"=>"advertisement", "8"=>"department", "9"=>"category", "10"=>"sub category", "11"=>"grievance", "12"=>"feedback", "13"=>"help");

return json_encode($role);
}
$getresult =  get_roles();
echo $getresult;
```

Comment: @Sandhiya No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

use json_encode to return json string like this:

```
return json_encode($role);
```

if you want the index start from 0, use `return json_encode(array_values($role));`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an array add role elements to array.

```
function get_roles(){
 $roles = array();
 $role = array("1"=>"user management", "2"=>"create", "3"=>"update","4"=>"publish", "5"=>"delete", "6"=>"image upload", "7"=>"advertisement", "8"=>"department", "9"=>"category", "10"=>"sub category", "11"=>"grievance", "12"=>"feedback", "13"=>"help");
 foreach($role as $x => $x_value) {
  $roles[] =  $x_value;   
 }
 return json_encode($roles);
}
echo get_roles();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function get_roles(){
$role = array("1"=>"user management", "2"=>"create", "3"=>"update","4"=>"publish", "5"=>"delete", "6"=>"image upload", "7"=>"advertisement", "8"=>"department", "9"=>"category", "10"=>"sub category", "11"=>"grievance", "12"=>"feedback", "13"=>"help");
foreach($role as $x => $x_value) {
return json_encode($role);
}

}
print_r(get_roles());
```